# Is it bad to use enum('y','n') instead of a boolean field in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

So a few years ago I saw the DB schema of a system developed by a 3rd party and noticed they used enum('y','n') instead of a boolean (tinyint) field. I don't know why but I loved it so much, I found it made things easier to read (totally subjective I know) but I adopted it and started using it ever since then. I suppose I could swap it for "true" and "false" but, what can I say, I just liked it.

Now that being said, are there any setbacks to doing things this way -- aside from maybe slightly annoying a programmer who'd come in late in the game?

Comment: why close vote this? This is a legit question

Comment: I'd say it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com rather than being closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is bad. You lose intuitive boolean logic with it (`SELECT * FROM user WHERE NOT banned` becomes `SELECT * FROM user WHERE banned = 'n'`), and you receive strings instead of booleans on your application side, so your boolean conditions there become cumbersome as well. Other people who work with your schema will get bitten by seeing flag-like column names and attempting to use boolean logic on them.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html#enum-nulls):

> If you insert an invalid value into an `ENUM` (that is, a string not present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is inserted instead as a special error value. This string can be distinguished from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the numeric value 0. See [Section 11.4.4, “ Index Values for Enumeration Literals ”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html#enum-indexes) for details about the numeric indexes for the enumeration values.
>
> If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid `ENUM` values result in an error.

In this respect, an `ENUM` results in different behaviour to a `BOOLEAN` type; otherwise I'm inclined to agree with [@lanzz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10882512/623041) that it makes integration with one's application that little bit less direct.

Answer (score 0):

One factor to consider is whether the people who wrote the original schema limit it to MySQL or not.  If it is only intended to run on MySQL, then adapting to MySQL makes sense.  If the same schema is intended to be usable with other DBMS, then a more generic schema design that works in all the relevant DBMS may be better for the people making the design.

With that said, the `enum` is moderately MySQL specific, but something equivalent to `enum` can easily be created in other DBMS:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
(
    ...
    FlagColumn   CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(FlagColumn IN ('y', 'n')),
    ...
);
```

The way that different DBMS handle BOOLEAN is not as uniform as you'd like it to be, SQL Standard notwithstanding (and the reason is, as ever, history; the less conformant systems had a variation on the theme of BOOLEAN before the standard did, and changing their implementation breaks the code of their existing customers).

So, I would not automatically condemn the use of `enum` over `boolean`, but it is better to use `boolean` for boolean flags.